# Transforming vector to vector with same name in R

Tags: r, function, vector

I am sorry for asking this silly question, I fear that answer is obvious but I really cant see it.

A want to apply a function on list of vectors using `lapply`. This function should transform the vector elements. First element of vector should stay untouched, and every next element should be sum of that and previous element. My code is

```
 trans<-function(x){
 if (length(x)==1){
 x<<-x
 }
 else{
 x[1]<<-x[1]
 for (i in 2:length(x)){
 x[i]<<-x[i-1]+x[i]}
 }}
```

The problem is, that incoming vector is untouched at all in output.
But, if I write the code like:

```
 trans<-function(x){
 b<<-NULL
 if (length(x)==1){
 b<<-x
 }
 else{
 b[1]<<-x[1]
 for (i in 2:length(x)){
 b[i]<<-x[i-1]+x[i]}
 }}
```

than vector `b` is rigth transformation of incoming vector. But because i want to `lapply` this function on list, i need to just transform that vectors, not create new ones.

Can you help me fix this?

example: incoming vector

```
 a<-c(1,2,3,5)
```

should be transformed into:

```
 (1,3,5,8)
```

Second function works well, problem is that I need to create vector `b` for that.

Comment: Something like `lapply(listOfVectors,cumsum)` ?

Comment: No, `cumsum()` sum all previous elements. I want to sum just ith element with i-1th element.

Comment: So `lapply(listOfVectors,function(v){v + c(0,head(v,-1))})` ?

Answer (score 1):

A little faster solution than @digEmAll's comment solution:

```
lapply(listOfVectors, function(l) {l + c(0, l[-length(l)])}

x <- list(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000))
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(digem= lapply(x, function(l) {l + c(0, head(l,-1))}),
           alex= lapply(x, function(l) {l + c(0, l[-length(l)])}))

Unit: microseconds
expr    min      lq       mean median       uq      max neval cld
 digem 61.581 68.4235 87.16445 82.679 100.9255  139.508   100   a
  alex 33.452 38.0135 64.86589 40.674  57.7800 1739.105   100   a
```